# Java Socket Programming in Overrided Start Function

Tags: java, network-programming

I am new to using JavaFx and its functionality. I am creating a 2 player checkers game that is played by local connection. I understand that in JavaFX you do not need a main class because the @Override on the start function basically serves as your main. Right now I have my connection trying to be made in that start function but it keeps spitting back java.net.BindException and java.lang.RuntimeException every time I try. I looked at my ports and it is not in use. I commented out the connection portion of the code and the app was able to run. Are you not able to connect in the start function?

Client Code:

```
 @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception, ClassNotFoundException, IOException,UnknownHostException {
       Scene scene1 = new Scene(createContent());
       primaryStage.setTitle("Client Side");
       primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
       primaryStage.show();

       socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1",1337);

       boolean end = false;
       boolean turn = true;
       Serializable ObjectInputStream;
        ObjectInputStream I = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        Serializable ObjectOutputStream;
        ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
        PrintStream p = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
       do
       {


        while(turn == true)
           {   
               temp1 = scan.nextInt();
               temp2 = scan.nextInt();
               Checker check = (Checker) I.readObject();
               check.relocate(temp1, temp2);
               turn = false;
           }
           while(turn == false)
           {

               p.println(sendX);
               p.println(sendY);
               o.writeObject(sendO);
               turn = true;


           }


       }while(end == false);

   }
```

Server Code is just reverse of that:

```
   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception, 
   ClassNotFoundException, IOException,UnknownHostException {
   Scene scene = new Scene(createContent());
   primaryStage.setTitle("Server Side");
   primaryStage.setScene(scene);
   primaryStage.show();

   serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1337);
   Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
   boolean end = false;
   boolean turn = true;
   Serializable ObjectInputStream;
   Serializable ObjectOutputStream;
    ObjectInputStream I = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
    PrintStream p = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
   do
   {


    while(turn == true)
       {   
        p.println(sendX);
        p.println(sendY);
        o.writeObject(sendO);
        turn = false;
       }
       while(turn == false)
       {


        temp1 = scan.nextInt();
        temp2 = scan.nextInt();
        Checker check = (Checker) I.readObject();
        check.relocate(temp1, temp2);
        turn = true;

       }


   }while(end == false); 

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use Try catch Block

```
 try {
       serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1337);
       Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
       System.out.println(e);
    }   

   boolean end = false;
   boolean turn = true;
   Serializable ObjectInputStream;
   Serializable ObjectOutputStream;
   ObjectInputStream I = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
   ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
   PrintStream p = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
  do
  {


     while(turn == true)
   {   
    p.println(sendX);
    p.println(sendY);
    o.writeObject(sendO);
    turn = false;
   }
   while(turn == false)
   {


    temp1 = scan.nextInt();
    temp2 = scan.nextInt();
    Checker check = (Checker) I.readObject();
    check.relocate(temp1, temp2);
    turn = true;

   }


   }while(end == false); 

   }
```

Comment: No dice. I am still getting the same errors. It doesn't seem to like me doing this in the start method. I don't know where else to do it at.

Comment: i thank you have another process bound to the same port.

Answer (score 0):

> you can try to have another process bound to the same port.

**TCPView** (Windows only) from Windows Sysinternals is my favorite app whenever I have a **JVM_BIND** error. It shows which processes are listening to which port. It also provides a convenient context menu to either kill the process or close the connection that is getting in the way.

Comment: interesting.. Now i am getting an EOFexception on the Client side on the line ObjectInputStream I = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());